# Amplify ssl certificate is expired - how to renew

Tags: aws-amplify

I had my website hosted in amplify for 2 years. I had everything working perfectly but now suddenly the certificate is expired. According to amazon it should renew automatically but it is not happening...

I have tried to reach amazon to fix the issue but they charge you to open a case about the mistakes they do so I have no idea how to fix it...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the domain and then adding it again solved this issue for me.

Hopefully, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have cleaned up some of my DNS records for the domain, and apparently some of them is for AWS ACM domain verification, and the renewal failed.

What worked for me was to remove the domain in Amplify and add it again.